# Send one email with table (specific columns)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send an email but the header names are repeated and I am seeing "NaN". What is causing this "NaN" and how do I remove the repeated header names? I have tried everything to fix the table but no luck. If you need a test sheet for this, let me know. TIA!

Logic is to send one email if:

- ColR = "Ready"
- ColF = recipient (repeated, if not only send one email)
- Send the details in the body as table (but not repeat the header names)
- After email is sent, mark ColR as "Sent" (currently, it marks "Sent" at the last entry of the repeated recipient name. Is it possible to mark all 3 rows with "Sent"?)

  function sendEmails_test() {
  var sheetID = "sheetIDxxx";

  ```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName('Sheet27');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var startrow = 2;  

  var datarange = sheet.getRange(startrow, 1, lastrow, lastCol);
  var dataVal = datarange.getValues();

  var nextEmail = '';
  var messageData = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < dataVal.length; i++) {
    if (i < dataVal.length - 1) {
      nextEmail = dataVal[i + 1][5] //look at next row
    } else { nextEmail = '' }

    var colD = dataVal[i][3];
    var colF = dataVal[i][5];
    var colH = dataVal[i][7];
    var colN = dataVal[i][13];
    var colP = dataVal[i][15];
    var colR = dataVal[i][17];

    // Introduction part of the email
    var messageIntro =
      '<HTML><BODY>'
      + '<p style="text-align:center"><b><h3>TEST</h3></b></p>'
      + "<br>"
      + '<p style="padding-left: 25px">Dear ' + colD + ","
      + '<p style="padding-left: 25px">Here are the details:</p>'

    messageData +=
      + '<table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse">'
      + '<tr>'
      + '<th>ColH</th><th>ColN</th><th>ColQ</th>'
      + '</tr>'
      + '<tbody>'
      + '<tr>'
      + '<td style="padding-left: 75px">' + colH + '</td><td style="padding-left: 75px">' + colN + '</td><td style="padding-left: 75px">' + colP + '</td>'
      + "</tr>"
      + "</tbody>"
      + "</table>"

    var messageEnd =

      + '<p style="padding-left: 25px">Thank you and Have a great day!<br>'
      + "</p>"
      + "</HTML></BODY>";

     if (colF != "" && colR == "Ready" && nextEmail != colF) {

      var subject = "TEST: " + colN;   
      MailApp.sendEmail(colF,
        subject,
        '',
        {
          'from': 'x@gmail.com',
          htmlBody: messageIntro + messageData + messageEnd
        });

      messageData = '';
      sheet.getRange(startrow + i, 18).setValue("Sent");
      // }
    }
  }
  ```

  }

[image]

*** **Hoping for this result without the repeated header rows** ***
[image]

---

*** Final result ***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `I am trying to send an email but the header names are repeated and I am seeing "NaN". What is causing this "NaN" and how do I remove the repeated header names?`, when I saw your script, `messageData += + '<table` and `var messageEnd = + '<p style=` are used. In this case, please remove `+` of `= + '`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.
- About `After email is sent, mark ColR as "Sent" (currently, it marks "Sent" at the last entry of the repeated recipient name. Is it possible to mark all 3 rows with "Sent"?)`, in your script, I guessed that all rows of "Ready" in column "R" are processed. In this case, how about replacing "Ready" with "Sent" after the loop was finished?

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendEmails_test() {
  var sheetID = "sheetIDxxx";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName('Sheet27');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var startrow = 2;

  var datarange = sheet.getRange(startrow, 1, lastrow, lastCol);
  var dataVal = datarange.getValues();

  var nextEmail = '';
  var messageData = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < dataVal.length; i++) {
    if (i < dataVal.length - 1) {
      nextEmail = dataVal[i + 1][5] //look at next row
    } else {
      nextEmail = '';
    }

    var colD = dataVal[i][3];
    var colF = dataVal[i][5];
    var colH = dataVal[i][7];
    var colN = dataVal[i][13];
    var colP = dataVal[i][15];
    var colR = dataVal[i][17];

    // Introduction part of the email
    var messageIntro =
      '<HTML><BODY>'
      + '<p style="text-align:center"><b><h3>TEST</h3></b></p>'
      + "<br>"
      + '<p style="padding-left: 25px">Dear ' + colD + ","
      + '<p style="padding-left: 25px">Here are the details:</p>'

    messageData += '<table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse">'
      + (messageData == "" ? '<tr><th>ColH</th><th>ColN</th><th>ColQ</th></tr>' : "")
      + '<tbody>'
      + '<tr>'
      + '<td style="padding-left: 75px">' + colH + '</td><td style="padding-left: 75px">' + colN + '</td><td style="padding-left: 75px">' + colP + '</td>'
      + "</tr>"
      + "</tbody>"
      + "</table>"

    var messageEnd = '<p style="padding-left: 25px">Thank you and Have a great day!<br>'
      + "</p>"
      + "</HTML></BODY>";

    if (colF != "" && colR == "Ready" && nextEmail != colF) {
      var subject = "TEST: " + colN;
      MailApp.sendEmail(colF, subject, '', { 'from': 'x@gmail.com', htmlBody: messageIntro + messageData + messageEnd });
      messageData = '';
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("R2:R" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Ready").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("Sent");
}
```

Comment: I followed your input and see the updated screenshot above. The "NaN" and marking the ColR with "Sent" seems to work. However, I still see the duplicated headers (see updated screenshot above). I must have missed something???

Comment: @user7935276 Thank you for replying. About `However, I still see the duplicated headers (see updated screenshot above).`, I couldn't notice this. So, I modified my answer for this. About `The "NaN" and marking the ColR with "Sent" seems to work.`, I couldn't understand it. Because when I tested my script using a sample Spreadsheet, the script works. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand it, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Here is test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xznoTAH2yS-Xnf-b3cCc0j8vxa9jS10WP1HjQapzNw/edit?pli=1#gid=1801932682

Comment: @user7935276 Thank you for replying. When I saw your current script in your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that my proposed modification is not correctly used at `messageData += ,,,`. Please use my proposed script correctly. Your current script is not my proposed script. I apologize for this situation. When I tested my proposed modified script using your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that your expected result is obtained. Can you test my proposed script again?

Comment: I adjusted the part under "messageData += ..." per your suggestion and it now works. Thank you so much for the help!